# Hands-on murderer

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I'm a deadly solution
>   Applied in revolution
>   With even distribution
>   On two parts in involution
>   Causing mass execution
>   Of things Lilliputian
>   Used by resolution
>   To achieve ablution

**What am I?**

**Hint:**

> Look at the title again

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are:

> **SOAP**

*I'm a deadly solution*

> 'Solution' here could be used in the context of being an answer to a problem or of a liquid mixture (e.g. handsoap from a bottle).

*Applied in revolution*
*With even distribution*
*On two parts in involution*

> This describes good hand-washing technique - applying soap evenly to both hands with rotating motions.

*Causing mass execution*
*Of things Lilliputian*

> Soap kills the millions of microscopic ('Lilliputian') bacteria that live upon your skin!

*Used by resolution*
*To achieve ablution*

> This is after all the whole point of using soap - you do it deliberately to clean your hands.

This explains the title too:

> Soap kills off ('murders') the bacteria on your hands. At least you won't go to jail for this though...

Comment: ...and if you think of how many keyboards died at the hands of ravaging programmers who have to work with SOAP protocol...

Answer (score 3):

I thought:

> razor

for some reason, which sorta works?

Comment: It's a bit sketchy, but it works (funnily enough), except for the first line. I suppose even the first line works, if you take "solution" in a different manner.